# Override `import` for more sophisticated module import

Tags: python, import

Is it possible to somehow override `import` so that I can do some more sophisticated operations on a module before it gets imported?

As an example: I have a larger application that uses `matplotlib` for secondary features that are not vital for the overall functionality of the application. In case that `matplotlib` is not installed I just want to mock the functionality so that the import and all calls to `matplotlib` functions appear to be working, just without actually doing anything. A simple warning should then just indicate that the module is not installed, though that fact would not impair the core functionality of the application. I already have an import function that, in the case that `matplotlib` is not installed, returns a `MagicMock` object instead of the actual module which just mimics the behavior of the `matplotlib` API.

So, all `import matplotlib...` or `from matplotlib import...` should then be automatically overridden by the corresponding function call. I could replace all `import` and `from ... import` expressions by hand but I'd like to make but there are a lot of them. I'd rather like to have this functionality automatically by overriding `import`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to replace the `__import__` function with your own implementation (described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)). Then if someone tries to import `matplotlib`, you just import a different module instead:

```
def _import(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name == 'matplotlib': # if someone tries to import matplotlib...
        name = 'my_mocked_matplotlib' # ...import the mocked version instead
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

import builtins
original_import = builtins.__import__
builtins.__import__ = _import
```

---

To restrict the custom import behavior to only a few modules, you can use introspection (with the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)) to find out from which module the import has been performed:

```
import inspect

def _import(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name == 'matplotlib': # if someone tries to import matplotlib...
        # find out which module is performing the import
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        module_path = frame.f_globals['__file__']

        # if the import is happening in module1 or module2, redirect it
        if module_path in ('/path/to/module1.py','/path/to/module2.py'):
            name = 'my_mocked_matplotlib' # ...import the mocked version instead

    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this globally, like, for a whole huge project that consists of several modules?

Comment: @HendrikWiese This should affect the whole project. For example if you place this code in `a.py` and then do `import b`, `b.py` will also use your custom import function. It works that way because it modifies the `builtins module, which is shared across the entire program.

Comment: Okay, one thing I've figured out about this is that it requires Python 3+. It seems I cannot do this with Python 2.7. Or is there a way?

Comment: @HendrikWiese You can use `__builtins__` instead of `import builtins` and `builtins` in python 2. And in python 3 as well. I've updated the code.

Comment: Great. One last thing: is it possible to limit this behavior to a specific part of the application, say, not all modules but only those underneath a particular folder?

Comment: @HendrikWiese You can handle that in the `_import` function itself, using introspection. See the updated answer. I've made the decision based on the module's `__file__`, but you might find it easier to do based on the `__name__`.

Answer (score 3):

For a truly sophisticated import (adding functionality, hooking, etc.) you can define a meta hook and override whatever portion of the import behavior that you need.  Example override script:

```
from os.path import (dirname, abspath, join, splitext)
from os import (listdir)
import importlib.util
import imp
import sys
_scripts_path = dirname(abspath(__file__))
_script_list = [splitext(f)[0] for f in listdir(_scripts_path) if splitext(f)[1] == '.py']

class custom_import_hook(object):
    def find_module(self, name, path):
        if name not in _script_list: return None
        return self
    
    class _cmds(object):
        @staticmethod
        def my_print(string):
            print(string)
    
    def load_module(self, name):
        sys.modules.setdefault(name, imp.new_module(name))
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('module.name', join(_scripts_path, f'{name}.py'))
        foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        for cmd in self._cmds.__dict__.keys():
            if cmd[0] == '_': continue
            setattr(foo, cmd, getattr(self._cmds, cmd))
        sys.meta_path.append(self)
        spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
        sys.meta_path.remove(self)
        return foo

meta_hook = custom_import_hook()
sys.meta_path.insert(0, meta_hook)
import test_script
```

then place in the same folder a script called 'test_script.py':

```
my_print('test')
```

and run the override script, you'll see that it defines 'my_print' such that when `test_script` is executed that your custom print command is used.  You can customize essentially anything you want at this point (e.g. wrapping a library with custom command replacement), since the hook gives you full control over the import.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **NO**... But you could and should catch `ImportError` for when the module is not there, and handle it then. Otherwise replacing all import statements with something else is the clever thing to do.

Comment: Alright, that's the way I've done it so far. I find it just a little cumbersome to replace all and every relevant import expression.